# Changing Visual Studio Test discovery working directory

Tags: visual-studio, googletest, working-directory

I have a big project with hundreds of existing GTest tests, some of them require a specific working directory to work correctly. It's fine when executing them since I can switch the current working directory before execution.
When the working directory is wrong, the test executable crashes with an access violation, even when executing with --gtest_list_tests (some static variable initialization fails).

The problem is that the Visual Studio test discovery agent (testhost.x86.exe) is running with the testhost.86.exe parent folder working directory, therefore causing the discovery to fail with an access violation.

Is there any way to change the Visual Studio test discovery working directory?

Comment: I don't see the whole picture, but IMHO you're trying to solve the wrong problem - changing the VS working directory while you should remove dependency on different working directory in your tests. After all, they should be running in CI for example, and changing working directory for each test suite would be a nightmare

Comment: When running the tests in CI I just execute the gtest exe with the correct working directory and it's enough. I don't need VS test explorer to work there.